# How does the canonical match-letrec implementation work?

Tags: macros, pattern-matching, scheme, metaprogramming

I am currently porting [Alex Shinn's canonical implementation of `match` for Scheme](http://synthcode.com/scheme/match.scm), which is used by almost all Scheme implementations, to another Lisp.

I've run into a total wall with `match-letrec`.   In [the simplified version of his implementation](http://synthcode.com/scheme/match-simple.scm), it's defined as follows:

```lisp
(define-syntax match-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ((pat expr)) . body)
     (match expr (pat . body)))
    ((_ ((pat expr) ...) . body)
     (match (list expr ...) ((pat ...) . body)))
    ((_ loop . rest)
     (match-named-let loop () . rest))
    ))

(define-syntax match-letrec
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ vars . body) (match-letrec-helper () vars . body))))

(define-syntax match-letrec-helper
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ((pat expr var) ...) () . body)
     (letrec ((var expr) ...)
       (match-let ((pat var) ...)
         . body)))
    ((_ (v ...) ((pat expr) . rest) . body)
     (match-letrec-helper (v ... (pat expr tmp)) rest . body))
    ))
```

Here's an example of how it looks when in use (Guile 1.8):

```
(match-letrec (((x y) (list 1 (lambda () (list a x))))
               ((a b) (list 2 (lambda () (list x a)))))
  (append (y) (b))
=> (2 1 1 2)
```

I'm having great difficulty understanding how this actually works.  When I expand this by hand as far as `match`, I get the following code (with automatic symbols indicated by `#{g...}`):

```lisp
(letrec ((#{g1} (list 1 (lambda () (list a x))))
         (#{g2} (list 2 (lambda () (list x a)))))
  (match (list #{g1} #{g2}) (((x y) (a b)) (append (y) (b))))
```

The automatic symbols are generated by the `tmp` substitution in the second rule of `match-letrec-helper`.  This expansion means that the lambda expressions are evaluated before `x` and `a` are bound, and therefore cannot capture them.

Can someone please explain how this syntax is supposed to be correctly expanded?  What have I missed?

Comment: That does not work in either of Racket 7.4, Chicken 4.13, or Guile 2.2.4. It also doesn't look anything like the implementation you linked to.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question to clarify that I quoted the simplified version of Alex Shinn's matcher in this question for expositional clarity, and added a link to it. I will build the latest Guile and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your example

```
(match-letrec (((x y) (list 1 (lambda () (list a x))))
               ((a b) (list 2 (lambda () (list x a)))))
  (append (y) (b))
=> (2 1 1 2)
```

is missing a close bracket.

After fixing that here's what happens:

```
> (match-letrec (((x y) (list 1 (lambda () (list a x))))
               ((a b) (list 2 (lambda () (list x a)))))
  (append (y) (b)))
. match: syntax error in pattern in: ((x y) (a b))
```

Even match-let is not working

```
> (match-let (((x y) (list 1 2)))
    x)
. match: syntax error in pattern in: (x y)
```

here's how to fix it:

```
(define-syntax match-let
  (syntax-rules (list)
    ((_ ((pat expr)) . body)
     (match expr (pat . body)))
    ((_ ((pat expr) ...) . body)
     (match (list expr ...) ((pat ...) . body)))
    ((_ loop . rest)
     (match-named-let loop () . rest))
    ))
```

now you can do this:

```
> (match-let (((list x y) (list 1 2)))
    (list x y))
'(1 2)
```

letrec is still not working

```
> (match-letrec (((list x y) (list 1 (lambda () (list a x))))
                 ((list a b) (list 2 (lambda () (list x a)))))
  (append (y) (b)))
. match: syntax error in pattern in: ((list x y) (list a b))
```

but this should get you a step closer, feel free to ask a new question with working code example once you understand these changes.